# `A dismissed Dismissible widget is still part of the tree` error occurred suddenly (FutureBuilder, ListView)

Tags: flutter, dart, dismissible

[image]

**`A dismissed Dismissible widget is still part of the tree.`**

`Make sure to implement the onDismissed handler and to immediately remove the Dismissible widget from the application once that handler has fired.`

I already know there are many questions about this issue in stackoverflow, and also read almost of them. But I have no idea why this happens because I have no setState issue, also dismissible key is correct. Could you find problem that I missed?? Someone said `Dismissible` should not be in `ListView` widget, but it has worked very well until yesterday even in the `ListView`. I tried `key: UniqueKey()` but it didn't work. Please let me know if you know any solutions. Thanks in advance.

```
Widget vocaBuilder() {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: loadTodayVoca(),
        builder: (context, snap) {
          if (snap.data.length == 0 || snap.data.isEmpty) {
            return Container();
          } else {
            return ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: snap.data.length,
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  Voca voca = snap.data[index];

                return GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        editPage(voca.id);
                      },
                      child: Dismissible(
                          direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
                          background: Container(
                              color: Colors.red,
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 23, right: 30)),    
                          key: Key(snap.data[index].toString()),
                         ...
                      onDismissed: (direction) {
                            setState((){
                            deleteVoca(voca.id);
                            snap.data.removeAt(index);
                          }); }));

 Future<void> deleteVoca(String id) async {
    DBHelper sd = DBHelper();
    await sd.deleteVoca(id);
  }

 Future<List<Voca>> loadTodayVoca() async {
    DBHelper sd = DBHelper();

    var list = await sd.vocas();
    return list
        .where((list) =>
            list.createTime ==
            DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd')
                .format(DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day)))
        .toList();
  }
```

Comment: What does `voca.toString()` return?

Comment: @Nitrodon ??? What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Hai，I have the same problem，and I solve it like this：modify the value of the key to become a unique value。
For you like this:`key:Key(snap.data[index].id.toString()),` or if `voca.id` is a string,you should `key:Key(snap.data[index].id)`